# overall or "as a whole" which is suitable to describe a shape?

Tags: adverbs

A golf ball has dimples, but the dimples are very small.  Can we say that a golf ball has a sphere shape ***as a whole*** or can we say a golf ball has an ***overall*** sphere shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In describing a shape, one would use "overall" if one is describing a size or complex shape by **ignoring** those parts that are an irregularity or complexity.  In the example of the golf ball, one is ignoring the concave dimples and looking only at what the size and shape would be without them.

One would use "as a whole" if one is describing a size or complex shape by **including** those parts that are an irregularity or complexity.  If the golf ball's dimples were convex bumps then, as a whole (by including the bumps), the circumference of the golf ball is greater than one with dimples.

Note:

"As a whole" is short for "[All the parts] taken as a whole" = overall (adv.)

"Overall" (adj.) = the maximum/greatest extent

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both actually.

> Overall, a golf ball has a spherical shape.
>
> As a whole, a golf ball is a sphere, albeit a dimpled one.

In a similar way I would say that, **overall**, Washington DC's National Mall is a long *rectangle*, bordered by parks, museums, and monuments: [image]

Granted it's not a perfect rectangle, but if you start at one end you can walk in a straight line all the way to the other end, and the Mall itself is a consistent width.  So *as a whole*, I can describe it as *rectangular*.

Unlike New York's Central Park, which is an actual rectangle: [image]

But here I can say, **overall** Central Park is covered with grass and trees (albeit with a small lake in the middle).

Answer (score 1):

I use **as a whole** and **overall** in the different **orders** of mentioning the whole and the parts.

### 1. Use as a whole after the parts are mentioned

I would use as a whole if I have mentioned the parts of an object which may have differences with it. I mean,

- Some parts of an object do not have a feature, but the object as a whole has it.

I'll say,

- A golf ball has dimples, but the dimples are very small. We can consider that a golf ball has a spherical shape as a whole.

Key: forget the dimples.

### 2. Use overall before or without the parts are mentioned

But if **having not said anything about the parts**, I prefer to use **overall**. For example,

- A golf ball has an overall sphere shape, but it has dimples.
- A golf ball has an overall sphere shape in spite of the dimples.

Key: plain statement.

### 3. Use as a whole without the parts are mentioned

I don't like to use **whole** when the parts are not obvious.

- A golf ball has a spherical shape as a whole.

The sentence may confuse me to pause, thinking what the parts of a golf ball are, if I do not know the dimples on golf balls. On the contrary, the words below will not:

- Overall, A golf ball has a spherical shape.

If the whole consists of relatively small groups of the same kind of thing, or something that is well known, It won't confuse.

- The U.S. population, as a whole, is very mobile compared to other countries.

This implies an omission meaning

- The population in some area of the U.s. is not mobile.

Key: forget the parts. I even don't want to say about it.

### 4. Use overall after the parts are mentioned

It implies **ignoring** the mentioned thing. but fo

- A golf ball has dimples, but overall, has a spherical shape.

To me, it means that

- A golf ball has dimples. If ignoring the dimples, a golf ball has a spherical shape.

Key: ignore the dimples at this time.

### Addition. Use overall if the content do not have an explicit relationship between the whole and the parts

- There are several little mistakes in your report, but overall, you have done a great work.